# htaccess rewrite, url doesn't work when i add a / at the end

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, slash

I have got a problem that seems to me something simple but i'm new to htaccess and can't find the solution.

i've got the following line in my htaccess (root map)

```
RewriteRule ^page1/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ page1.php?name=$1
RewriteRule ^page1/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ page1.php?name=$1
```

When i enter the the following url it works without a problem

```
www.myexample.com/page1/variable
```

the strange thing happens when I add a / at the end. Then the page can't get the GET value out of the URL.

Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: Do you have any other rules in your .htaccess?

Comment: yeah that was the problem, but now i fixed that, there is a new one. I'd like to use the rule matt suggested:

RewriteRule ^page1/(.*)$ page1.php?url=$1 

but without the "page1" at the beginning like: 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page1.php?url=$1 

The problem is when i type myexample.com or exmaple.com/contact.php it also loads page1.php and it needs only to be loaded if theres something like /variable/ behind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the ending /$ sign on the first rule

```
RewriteRule ^page1/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) page1.php?name=$1
```

Or you can continue to capture data

```
RewriteRule ^page1/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/(.*)$ page1.php?name=$1
```

Ultimately if you want to keep capturing more data with "/" as a delimiter, I suggest doing

```
RewriteRule ^page1/(.*)$ page1.php?url=$1
```

Then use the server side script to determine what to do.

Comment: with your last suggestion, did you mean i have to fetch the end of the URL using $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; instead of $_GET["url"]?